# Need help understanding the proof of the Hahn Banach theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

I don't understand why $D(\hat g)$ is a vector space. I can see the result as being true if the union were finite for then then union would be some vector space itself in the union. Also, how is $\hat g$ a linear functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows (as mentioned) from the fact, that $C$ is a chain. In particular, if $x,y \in \mathcal{D}(\hat g)$, you find $g_x, g_y$ with $x \in \mathcal{D}(g_x)$, $y \in \mathcal{D}(g_y)$. Since $C$ is a chain, we have $\mathcal{D}(g_x) \subset \mathcal{D}(g_y)$ or $\mathcal{D}(g_y) \subset \mathcal{D}(g_x)$. Since both are subspaces, we find $x + y \in \mathcal{D}(\hat g)$.

Similarly, you can show the linearity of $\hat g$.